# php regular expression and replace

Tags: php, regex

Would be possible with php and one regular expression to do the following. Get all hyperlinks inside of a content and rewrite them if the top level domain of hyperlink is matching a given tld name from array.

Now have a regular expression which rewrites  all hyperlinks in a given content

```
preg_replace('/<a(.*)href="([^"]*)"(.*)>/','<a$1href="goto.php?url=$2"$3>', $content);
```

example

```
$tld = array("http://www.example.com","http://www.test.com");

if <a href="www.example.com">example</a> than <a href="/goto.php?url= www.example.com"</a>;
```

Comment: Please, use a DOM parser instead.

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: oh man is getting complicated I loose my faith.

Comment: Does that not work or something?  What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice, I have been ending up to use php's DOM parser

Answer (score 1):

You might want to solidify your regex a bit...

```
$pattern = <<<EOL
/<a([^>]+)href\s*=\s*(['" ]?)([^"'> ]*)(['" ]?)([^>]*)>/si
EOL;

$replacement = "<a$1href='goto.php?url=$3'$5>";

preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

Not able to test this right now, so there may be a typo...

Comment: Thanks a lot I'm going to give a try with it